# Oracle Select Query Load Optimization

Tags: sql, oracle

I have two table A and B. A has a column b_id which act as a foreign key reference for a many to one relationship.

So is there any load difference in Oracle when executing the query like

```
select A.* from A, B where A.b_id=B.ID and B.ID=?  -- auto-generated by hibernate
```

and

```
select * from A where b_id = ?    -- Created manually
```

UPDATE : I need data from only table A

Comment: Yes, there is a load difference if you query two tables instead of just one.  It appears that you have already queried `B` because you have the correct ID, so dont query it again.

Comment: Oracle should be clever enough to figure this out. Try to get an execution plan.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For sure there will be a difference between both queries, the first one is getting data from two tables and the second one is just querying one unique table.

Even if you don't return any results of table B in the first query, these data are used for the jointure condition (not the case in the second query).

Comment: When only table A columns are returned, I can imagine (without knowing it) that the oracle optimizer skips the unnessessary join. A look at the explain plan would be interesting.

Comment: @DirkNM: One can hope so. However, it is not completely trivial as the SQL also calls for the existence of a matching id in the table B. That can probably be inferred from a foreign key constraint and thus skipped from the query (if the constraint has been declared to Oracle, not just to Hibernate).

Comment: @Thilo constraint is declared in Oracle also.

Comment: Well, get the execution plan. If it is not the same, try to coax Hibernate into a better query (good luck)...

Comment: But at the end, if your tables haven't millions of rows, you'll probably not notice a big difference in term of performance. The `Execution Plan` created by Oracle will optimize the process.